# JavaScript RSA encryption to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I need to authenticate myself via PHP script on remote website, and website uses JS-based RSA encryption for passwords. Here's the code from website:

```
function rsa_encrypt(strPlainText) {
    var strModulus = "some_random_string";
    var strExponent = "10001";
    var rsa = new RSAKey();
    rsa.setPublic(strModulus, strExponent);
    var res = rsa.encrypt(strPlainText);
    if (res) {
        return res;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Browsed a lot of topics on this website, and found that the recommended way is to use phpseclib (if there's another one, let me know). However, using basic example from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#encrypt,enc2 I get just an empty page. I entered `some_random_string` into `$rsa->loadKey('...');` - not sure if I did it right? However, I can't see a place to enter `strExponent` (which is 10001) in this example.

So I tried another solution - [Encrypt and Decrypt text with RSA in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484246/encrypt-and-decrypt-text-with-rsa-in-php) and modified my code to look the following:

```
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$privatekey = "some_random_string";

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);

$plaintext = new Math_BigInteger('10001');
echo $rsa->_exponentiate($plaintext)->toBytes();
```

However, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function abs() on null in Math\BigInteger.php on line 1675
```

The solution was posted some time ago, so I guess something got changed in phpseclib library during this time, and I'm just not sure how to re-modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

Popular formats for RSA keys typically contain both the exponent and the modulus within them. See, for example, my answer to [I understand the mathematics of RSA encryption: How are the files in ~/.ssh related to the theory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289989/569976) for a more detailed discussion of one particular type of key format.

If you have the exponent and modulo as distinct values try doing this:

```
$rsa->loadKey([
    'e' => new Math_BigInteger('10001', 16),
    'n' => new Math_BigInteger('some_random_string', 16);
]);
```

Note the `, 16` bit. [65537](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_(number)) (10001 in hex) is a common RSA exponent. `Math_BigInteger` assumes, by default, that the number being passed to it is in base-10, unless you specifically tell it otherwise. One requirement of RSA is that e be coprime to either phi(n) or lcm(n). 65537 is trivially coprime because it *is* prime. 10001 is not prime. It can be factored into 73*137.